# Creating nested tags using document.createElement

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a nested tag using javascript [createElement](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Document/createElement) function like

```
<li><span class="toggle">Jan</span></li>
```

Can anyone give me an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The simplest way is with `createElement()` and then set its `innerHTML`:

```
var tag = document.createElement("li");
tag.innerHTML = '<span class="toggle">Jan</span>';
```

You can then add it to the document with `.appendChild()` wherever you want it to go.

Comment: And maybe you should `clone()` function instead `createElement()` for every `li` element.

Comment: Why `clone()`?  What advantage does that have over `createElement()` for this purpose?

Comment: If I'm not wrong `cloneNode()` should has some advantages for memory issues instead creating for every time a new element. In this way, you just referring the `tag` (which is created first) element and no more mem allocation with creating new elements. `var li=createElement("li"), l; l=li.cloneNode(true); l.innerHTML="..."; l.cloneNode(true); l.innerHTML="..."; so on...`

Comment: @qeremy - I've never heard of `cloneNode()` using less memory.  Do you have a reference on that?

Comment: I have no reference for it (cos I don't remember where I've seen it) and told at first "if I'm not wrong" :). And simply thinking; `var li=document.createElement("li");` Now, I have one `var` at memory and not pushing-stuffing `var`s anymore to memory, but just referring to it when I need same thing writing `l=li.cloneNode(true)` and also overwriting on `l` every time. I think this must be useful and has advantages. Or writing like this? `var li; li=document.createElement("li"); do someth... li=document.createElement("li"); do s...; li=document.createElement("li"); ...`

Comment: this may work for some element types, but one I just added (an iframe inside a noscript for google tag manager) required document.createElement('noscript').appendChild(document.createElement('iframe')) sort of thing instead.  See [Vatev's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11840922/7032554).

Comment: @SubjectiveReality - This answer is for regular HTML entities, not script tags.  Also, an iframe is a different kind of element as it creates a whole new browsing context inside it and plays by a different set of rules.

Answer (score 19):

```
var li = document.createElement('li');
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.className = 'toggle';
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Jan'));
li.appendChild(span);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a function that is suitable for use when we want to convert an nested JSON to html tags.You can change it according to your needs or event convert it to JQuery. I use this to convert a JSON response to html.

```js
let createContentByJson = function (target, obj) {
    const el = document.createElement(obj.tag);
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('class'))
        el.classList.add(obj.class);
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('text'))
        el.textContent = obj.text;
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('id'))
        el.id = obj.id;
    target.append(el);
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('inner'))
        obj.inner.forEach((inner_el) => {
            createContentByJson(el, inner_el);
        });
};

createContentByJson(document.querySelector('#target'),{
  tag: 'div',
  class: 'parent-div',
  id: 'parent',
  inner:[
    {
      tag: 'p',
      class: 'child-class1',
      text: 'child1'
    },
    {
      tag: 'p',
      class: 'child-class2',
      text: 'chid2'
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```